# SWI Prolog ignores discontiguous predicate

Tags: prolog

I'm struggling to understand how to properly use the `discontiguous/1` predicate in (SWI) Prolog.

Let `buumi.pl` be this little file of pseudo-facts:

```
discontiguous(buumi/1).

buumi(eins).
buri(zwei).
buumi(drei).
```

Running `swipl -s Buumi.pl` however still gives this warning:

```
% swipl -s Buumi.prolog
Warning: [...]/Buumi.prolog:5:
        Clauses of buumi/1 are not together in the source-file
```

The documentation is quite vague and simply states

`discontiguous :PredicateIndicator, ...`

but gives no concrete example on how to use it.  I've
found some examples that suggest that I'm using it correctly; at the very least,
swipl doesn't complain, but then again, it doesn't honour my request either.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`discontiguous/1` is an ISO directive. You have to put it as

```
:- discontiguous(pred/2).
```

at the beginning of the Prolog text.

Comment: Thanks. Why the SWI PRolog manual can't just say that baffles me

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SWI-Prolog version 8.2.4 for x86_64-linux.

My WARNINGS say to enter

```
:- discontiguous pred-name/1.
```

This eventually did work and I get an output like below after loading the prolog file:

```
?- consult('animals.pl').     (My entry)

  true.                       (SWIPL response)
```

Each predicate name has to be explicitly entered or else SWIPL assumes the default rule for undeclared predicates and outputs the same old warning.